# Как изменять статус пользователя Discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

Я хочу изменять свой статус (Пользователя, НЕ бота) в Discord с помощью скрипта на Python.

Пробовал использовать https://github.com/netgian/Discord-User-API, но выдаёт ошибку 401.

Как это можно реализовать иначе?

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, что именно Вы хотите изменить в своём статусе. Тоесть при помощи скрипта вы хотите выдать себе роль, или как?
Возможно, Вам стоит создать бота для подобных целей и уже через него вручать себе статус администратора или роли. Но Всё же легче будет сделать это врчну.

Comment: Статус устанавливается лично пользователем и отображается не только на вашем сервере, а на всех. Поэтому бот не может изменить его, в отличие от никнейма.

Answer (score 0):

Это всё делается через betterdiscord.
Позже после его установки устанавливаешь плагин на статус.
Предупреждаю! Не качай лишнего т.к. дискорд может снести тебе аккаунт.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]